# Does the .Net run-time compiler support C# 3.0?

Tags: c#, .net

It looks like the run-time compiler doesn't support the same language as the command-line compiler so if you want to use lambda expressions, extensions methods or LINQ, well, you're stuck.

There's more detail here:

http://metadatalabs.com/blog/

Is this correct or is there a work-around?  (Short of spawning the command-line compiler, of course.)

Comment: Why is spawning the command-line compiler not an option? It seems like a valid solution of the runtime compiler refuses to work.

Comment: The client would have to install the command-line tools for our software to work.  It's a burden on the client and a configuration headache but if there is no other option it's what we'll have to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This guy's blog seems to have the answer

[CodeDomProviders](http://andersnoras.com/blogs/anoras/archive/2008/04/13/codedomproviders-and-compiler-magic.aspx)

Looks like the factory defaults the instance it returns to 2.0.

This seems like a pretty crazy technique. Somewhere Paul Graham is crying.

Answer (score 2):

I've been using this, and it seems to work when compiling using .Net 3.5

```
CodeDomProvider provider = new CSharpCodeProvider(new Dictionary<string, string> { { "CompilerVersion", "v3.5" } });
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the documentation of the [CSharpCodeProvider constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb537926.aspx):

> The value for providerOptions is
>   obtained from the 
>   element in the configuration file. You
>   can identify the version of the
>   CSharpCodeProvider you want to use by
>   specifying the 
>   element, supplying "CompilerVersion"
>   as the option name, and supplying the
>   version number (for example, "v3.5")
>   as the option value. You must precede
>   the version number with a lower case
>   "v".

Answer (score 0):

I haven´t tried that, but it sounds crazy..

In the future that wont be a problem, since the .NET team are going to have the C# compiler available as a service, which means you can work with the real C# compiler in your code. Take a look at this video:

http://channel9.msdn.com/pdc2008/TL16/